App stays on white screen after being reopened
I have a qml file which purpose is to redirect the user if his authentication token is valid. If it is valid it redirects him to the main page and if not it goes to the authenticaton qml file.
When I first open the app everything seems fine, but once I open it second time I get white screen.
Here is the qml file I am talking about:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Fusion 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    font.family: "Montserrat"

    Material.theme: Material.Light
    Material.accent: "#001b2a"

    Loader {
       id: componentLoader
       anchors.centerIn: parent

    }

    Component.onCompleted: function() {
        networkManager.authenticated_get("http://192.168.1.2:5000/api/authenticate");
    }

    Connections {
        target: networkManager
        ignoreUnknownSignals: true

        function onOperationFinished(responseData, isError) {
            var json = JSON.parse(networkManager.convertToJsonString(responseData));

            if(isError) {
               componentLoader.source = "Auth.qml"
               return;
            }
            storageManager.attachAuthToken(json.auth_token);
            console.log(storageManager.getAuthToken());
            componentLoader.source = "home.qml"
            
        }
    }
}

I load this qml from my main.cpp
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

I am confident that onCompleted gets called only once and that is the first time when I open the app, so when I reopen it I suppose it goes again to this very same qml, but onCompleted doesn't get called. So most likely the problem comes from here, but then how can I do it in such way when I open the app it sends this request to validate the user everytime ?
Could someone help me out here ?
